# Weird URL bypassing routing, parenthesis capital letter parenthesis anything two closing parentheses

Tags: asp.net, web-config, uri

I stumbled upon some strange behaviour today on a website at work. Our SEO consultant wanted some strange looking links taken away from Googles index, a seemingly straight-forward task. But it turned out to be very difficult.

The website was a .net MVC 5.2.3 application. We looked at routing, our own libraries etc. Nothing strange. After a while we gave up and tried simply redirect request to these urls by setting up a rule in web.config. Turns out these URL:s are unmatchable! Somehow under the right conditions the critical part of the URL seem to avoid matching rules as well as routing later on in the MVC application.

We narrowed down the mystical URL:s to the format `(T(anything))` where T can by any capital letter and anything can be eh, anything. This is placed in the beginning of the URL as if it were a directory. In regex: `\([A-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\)`

I've tested and found the same behaviour on:

- .net MVC5 sites
- .net MVC3 sites
- .net Web Forms sites
- http://asp.net
- http://stackoverflow.com

Some examples from stackoverflow.com:

- Bypasses routing: https://stackoverflow.com/(K(jonas))/questions
- Routes normal (404): https://stackoverflow.com/jonas/questions
- Bypasses routing: https://stackoverflow.com/(G(hello))/users/1049710/jonas-%C3%84ppelgran
- Routes normal (404): [https://stackoverflow.com/gandhello/users/1049710/jonas-Äppelgran](https://stackoverflow.com/gandhello/users/1049710/jonas-%C3%84ppelgran)

It doesn't seem to affect the whole web, so it shouldn't be a browser or HTTP issue. Some examples:

- Routes normal (404): http://php.net/(T(testing))/downloads
- Routes normal (404): https://www.iana.org/(T(testing))/domains/reserved

**Can anybody explain what is going on?**

And what I can do to prohibit these URL:s to bypass routing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a feature called a "cookieless session" in ASP.NET. See "Cookieless SessionIDs" section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx) in the MSDN docs.

The basic idea is that instead of storing the session id (if session state is enabled) in a cookie, it's now embedded in the URL.

We (Stack Overflow) disable session state entirely (by setting `sessionState` mode to `off`). As far as I know, the end result is that any time one of the URLs that match the session id format is used, that information is simply discarded.

None of the links leading to us in Google include it either, which makes me think that your site may be configured to actually generate session IDs in URLs? Short of disabling the feature, there's probably not much you can do here. Although, see "Regenerating Expired Session Identifiers" on the MSDN page I linked above to see how to at least prevent accidental session sharing if that's not already done.